# Can I overlay a map on my base layer when their resolutions are different?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, arcgis

I am trying to overlay an ArcGISCache layer on top of another ArcGISCache base layer. I'm unable to get the overlay to show and I am not sure what is wrong. I modified this example to get my started: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/arcgiscache_jsonp.html

I'm prototyping in http://jsfiddle.net/Sq9hE/15/

When I change the map constructor to instantiate with `yorkLayer`'s resolutions, I can see the tiles from the York map but not the base layer. How can I create this map object so both the base layer and the overlay are shown?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the javascript api before, but I encountered what sounds like a similar issue working with the ArcGIS api for Android.  If you are using two cached tile layers it may be that they were not cached using transparency.  It could be that they are both active but you only see the top layer's tiles.

Comment: In my situation I was able to recreate the tile cache for my overlay features using a different image format that supports transparency.  [Image Cache Formats](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/10/17/tips-for-choosing-a-cache-image-format/)